# how to save OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver intofile in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium in c# and after work with ChromeDriver , i need to save this and after a day again load this session and work with. is there any way to save ChromeDriver into a file in my system and load it  to program again?

Answer (score 1):

You can't save an C# Object into an file (You can serialize it to JSON for example and save it) but for your chromedriver it's not possible.

If you need to keep logged into some websites, you can save browser cookies instead, and load them when you restart your program.

If you need to save more globally the ChromeDriver state, just provide a profile directory to your ChromeDriver at initialization.

Comment: You're welcome. If your question has been awnsered, accept the awnser please.